# Does the "south-korean" tag need to exist?

Tags: discussion

I feel like it can apply to nearly every question here, as south Korean is the "default" Korean.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've come to the same conclusion over in this other meta question: [Use of dialect tags](http://meta.korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2/use-of-dialect-tags)